# Error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-invalid-source-encoding’ [-Werror] within building Mesos

Tags: c++, ubuntu, mesos

My operating system is Ubuntu 18.10. I follow these steps on three nodes:
To install Mesos I did these steps one by one without any errors, except every node has already had Open JDK 8, so I did not install Open JDK 8 again.

```
   sudo apt-get update
   sudo apt-get install -y tar wget git
   sudo apt-get install -y openjdk8-jdk (I did not do that)
   sudo apt-get install -y autoconf libtool
   sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-six python- 
   virtualenv libcurl4-nss-dev libsasl2-dev libsasl2-modules maven 
   libapr1-dev libsvn-dev zlib1g-dev iputils-ping
```

The problem is begin when I want to build Mesos. I did these steps for that:

```
cd mesos-1.7.0
./bootstrap
mkdir build
cd build
../configure
make
```

My IP addresses are 150.20.11.137,150.20.11.134,150.20.11.157. I downloaded Mesos package on all of them and extracted in the same path.
I did <../configure> on every node without any problems, but when I run "make" I got this error on each node:

> third_party/cares/cares/ares_init.c: In function ‘ares_dup’:
> third_party/cares/cares/ares_init.c:301:17: error:
> argument to ‘sizeof’ in ‘strncpy’ call is the same expression as the source; did
> you mean to use the size of the destination? [-Werror=sizeof-pointer-
> memaccess]

> ```
>        sizeof(src->local_dev_name));
> ```

```
             ^
```

> third_party/cares/cares/ares_init.c: At top level:

> cc1: error: unrecognized command line option ‘-Wno-invalid-source-
> encoding’ [-Werror]
> cc1: all warnings being treated as errors

> make[4]: *** [Makefile:2635: /home/spark/mesos-
> 1.7.0/build/3rdparty/grpc-
> 1.10.0/objs/opt/third_party/cares/cares/ares_init.o] Error 1

> make[4]: Leaving directory '/home/spark/mesos-
> 1.7.0/build/3rdparty/grpc-1.10.0'

> make[3]: *** [Makefile:1446: grpc-1.10.0-build-stamp] Error 2

> make[3]: Leaving directory '/home/spark/mesos-1.7.0/build/3rdparty'

> make 2]: *** [Makefile:1035: all-recursive] Error 1

> make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/spark/mesos-1.7.0/build/3rdparty'

> make[1]: *** [Makefile:765: all] Error 2

> make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/spark/mesos-1.7.0/build/3rdparty'

> make: *** [Makefile:768: all-recursive] Error 1

Comment: I used another version of Mesos, but I got  this error **src/zookeeper.c:3504:21: error: ‘%d’ directive writing between 1 and 5 bytes into a region of size between 0 and 127 [-Werror=format-overflow=]
     sprintf(buf,"%s:%d",addrstr,ntohs(port));** I do n't know, it is a bug of Mesos or I do something wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I updated "c-ares" and installed "libssl-dev". After that I got this error: **error: type qualifiers ignored on cast result type [-Werror=ignored-qualifiers]
       static_cast<const uint32_t>(target_window());**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved. The problem was because of GCC version. GCC version in Ubuntu 18.10 is 8.2.0. I installed gcc-5 and g++-5 with this instruction:

```
 sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-toolchain-r/test
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install gcc-5 g++-5
```

Then to choose GCC version that I want, I have to install "update-alternatives" for gcc. Therefore, I run these commands:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-5 500 --slave 
/usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-5
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gcc gcc /usr/bin/gcc-8 800 --slave 
/usr/bin/g++ g++ /usr/bin/g++-8
```

After that I chose gcc-5 with this command :

```
sudo update-alternatives --config gcc
```

Moreover, I had an error related to OpenSSL; then I installed it via this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
```

After those modifications, I started to install Mesos and it installed without any errors. I hope this illustration was helpful for others.

Comment: Better to *not* do that `update-alternatives` dance, and use `../configure CC=gcc-5 CXX=g++-5`

Comment: Dear @o11c, thank your for your suggestion. Mesos have been installed without any errors; I will do your suggestion for other installation. Would you please tell me if I can change gcc alternatives to gcc-8 without any problems?